# Selenium WebDriver findElement(By.xpath()) not working

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use xpath to click on an elemnt. But its not working.

```
<a id="ProductListProductLink_414303" data-test="ProductListProductLink_3" href="http://uat-staging.wc7.dunelm.com/product/dorma-red-capri-collection-flat-sheet?searchTerm=sheet double">
```

I tried in may ways. but did not work.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: can you please provide the code you have been using for clicking on the element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you **pass xpath id using ('') single quote**. When you copy xpath from browser it comes with double quote.

Below example will help you for basic xpath idea :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.google.com");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbqfq']")).sendKeys("software testing");
```

Comment: He does not have to use single quote. But it is cleaner to use single quote. He can use escape character such as "\" instead. And, looking at his html snippet it can be assumed that that Id is randomly generated and, thus your xpath will not help him.